# Is there a way to access xml tag like <yweather:condition only with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

I can do it using DOMXPath but i would like to do it with only DOMDocument..

I tried something like

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('yweather:condition')
//or
$dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('yweather','condition')
```

but neither worked.

someone knows how to do it? or i will need to use DOMXPath?

Comment: The first parameter is a namespace URI, not the simple namespace name.  See examples [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the full namespace, not yweather which is the local name.

```
getElementsByTagNameNS('fullname_space', 'condition')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude', 'condition') as $element) {
    echo 'local name: ', $element->localName, ', prefix: ', $element->prefix, "\n";
}
```

Where http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude would be the url you attached the namespaced to.